# How to open an Ubuntu VMWare VMDK file on a Windows box

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

Someone made a .vmdk file for Ubuntu Linux that I'd like to open up in VMWare Workstation 12 Pro on a Windows 10 guest operating system. I tried creating a new Virtual Machine, selecting an an iso of Ubuntu 18.04.1 as the operating system, and adding the .vmdk file as an existing hard disk. I did a fresh install of Ubuntu, but wasn't able to find a directory which was supposed to exist on the computer represented by the vmdk file. I also tried just creating a new VM and selecting Ubuntu as the operating system and not using an iso file, but then I get an "Operating system not found" error.  I have also tried mounting the vmdk as a virtual disk just so I could verify that the contents existed, but Windows gives me a prompt for formatting the disk.

Here is the vmx file:

```
.encoding = "windows-1252"
config.version = "8"
virtualHW.version = "12"
numvcpus = "4"
cpuid.coresPerSocket = "4"
vcpu.hotadd = "TRUE"
scsi0.present = "TRUE"
scsi0.virtualDev = "lsilogic"
sata0.present = "TRUE"
memsize = "1024"
mem.hotadd = "TRUE"
sata0:1.present = "TRUE"
sata0:1.autodetect = "TRUE"
sata0:1.deviceType = "cdrom-image"
ethernet0.present = "TRUE"
ethernet0.connectionType = "nat"
ethernet0.virtualDev = "e1000"
ethernet0.wakeOnPcktRcv = "FALSE"
ethernet0.addressType = "generated"
usb.present = "TRUE"
ehci.present = "TRUE"
ehci.pciSlotNumber = "35"
sound.present = "TRUE"
sound.fileName = "-1"
sound.autodetect = "TRUE"
mks.enable3d = "TRUE"
svga.graphicsMemoryKB = "786432"
serial0.present = "TRUE"
serial0.fileType = "thinprint"
pciBridge0.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge4.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge4.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge4.functions = "8"
pciBridge5.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge5.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge5.functions = "8"
pciBridge6.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge6.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge6.functions = "8"
pciBridge7.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge7.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge7.functions = "8"
vmci0.present = "TRUE"
hpet0.present = "TRUE"
usb.vbluetooth.startConnected = "TRUE"
displayName = "DnD"
guestOS = "ubuntu-64"
nvram = "DnD.nvram"
virtualHW.productCompatibility = "hosted"
powerType.powerOff = "soft"
powerType.powerOn = "soft"
powerType.suspend = "soft"
powerType.reset = "soft"
extendedConfigFile = "DnD.vmxf"
uuid.bios = "56 4d 79 a7 0a cc cb 46-0b 31 26 48 2c f1 b1 38"
uuid.location = "56 4d 79 a7 0a cc cb 46-0b 31 26 48 2c f1 b1 38"
migrate.hostlog = ".\DnD-2abf88a2.hlog"
pciBridge0.pciSlotNumber = "17"
pciBridge4.pciSlotNumber = "21"
pciBridge5.pciSlotNumber = "22"
pciBridge6.pciSlotNumber = "23"
pciBridge7.pciSlotNumber = "24"
scsi0.pciSlotNumber = "16"
usb.pciSlotNumber = "32"
ethernet0.pciSlotNumber = "33"
sound.pciSlotNumber = "34"
vmci0.pciSlotNumber = "36"
sata0.pciSlotNumber = "37"
ethernet0.generatedAddress = "00:0c:29:f1:b1:38"
ethernet0.generatedAddressOffset = "0"
vmci0.id = "754037048"
monitor.phys_bits_used = "42"
vmotion.checkpointFBSize = "4194304"
vmotion.checkpointSVGAPrimarySize = "33554432"
cleanShutdown = "TRUE"
softPowerOff = "FALSE"
usb:1.speed = "2"
usb:1.present = "TRUE"
usb:1.deviceType = "hub"
usb:1.port = "1"
usb:1.parent = "-1"
workingDir = "."
scsi0:0.present = "TRUE"
scsi0:0.fileName = "F:\Virtual Machines\S m S front end\SmS.vmdk"
scsi0:0.redo = ""
svga.guestBackedPrimaryAware = "TRUE"
toolsInstallManager.updateCounter = "4"
checkpoint.vmState = "SmS-2abf88a2.vmss"
toolsInstallManager.lastInstallError = "21004"
tools.remindInstall = "TRUE"
sata0:1.fileName = "F:\Virtual Machines\ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso"
scsi0:1.present = "FALSE"
floppy0.present = "FALSE"
usb:0.present = "TRUE"
usb:0.deviceType = "hid"
usb:0.port = "0"
usb:0.parent = "-1"
```

Comment: You can browse VMDK files with 7-Zip.

Comment: Not sure about that - 7-Zip doesn't recognize the .vmdk file as an archive.

Comment: It works for me on the `.vmdk` file, though it doesn't interpret the `.vmx` file. I have checked on both Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10. It works with both the graphical and command-line interfaces.

Comment: Multiple ways: https://www.altaro.com/vmware/extract-content-vmdk-files/  Are you sure you have all the files?  How big is the vmdk?  Was there a "flat-file" labeled vmdk with it?